# solving system of equations with constant $i$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

What are the values of *$a,b,c$* given the system of equations given below: 
$a+b+ab=i$ 
$b+c+bc=2i$ 
$c+a+ac=3i$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which aspect of the problem is troubling you? Adding answers to questions such as these will help get other users provide better answers.

Comment: eve already try elimination and substitution but failed to got the answer. maybe there are other ways im missing. will anyone there help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the equations be $$a+b+a\,b=X\tag 1$$ $$b+c+b\,c=Y\tag 2$$ $$c+a+c\,a=Z\tag 3$$ Eliminate $b$ from $(1)$ and $c$ from $(3)$; this gives
$$b=\frac{X-a}{a+1}\qquad c=\frac{Z-a}{a+1}$$ Replace these expressions in $(2)$ and simplify; this leads to $$ (Y+1)\,a^2+2 ( Y+1)\,a+(-X Z-X+Y-Z)=0$$ which is a quadratic in $a$.

Replacing $X=i$, $Y=2i$, $Z=3i$ and solving the quadratic which becomes $$a^2+2a -\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{8 i}{5}\right)=0 $$ gives $$a_1=-1+2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}+i\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\qquad a_2=-1-2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}-i\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}$$ $$b_1=-1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\qquad b_2=-1-\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$$ $$c_1=-1+\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}+i\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\qquad c_2=-1-\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-i\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$$

Comment: i think it should be "eliminate $a$ from (1) and eliminate $a$ from (3)" please check @Claude Leibovici

Comment: No. I solved $(1)$ for $b$ and $(3)$ for $c$. In such a way, everything is given as functions of $a$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that adding $1$ to each equation gives that

$(a+1)(b+1)=i+1$. 
$(b+1)(c+1)=2i+1$ 
$(c+1)(a+1)=3i+1$.

Multiply these gives us that $((a+1)(b+1)(c+1))^2=(i+1)(2i+1)(3i+1)=-10$.

This implies that $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=\pm \sqrt{10}i$.

Proceed with Calculations from here.

Comment: what method will be use to solve the last equation? i'm sorry but i don't know what to do from here.

Comment: can you please further explain from here. i know this will work but i dont know what to do next.

Comment: Note that dividing the first and final equation will give $c+1=\frac{\pm \sqrt{10}i}{i+1}$, or $c+1=\pm (\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}i)$. In the same way, we can know $a+1$, $b+1$.

Comment: $c=\pm (\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}i)-1$

Comment: $c=\pm (\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}i)-1=\frac{\pm(\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{10})-2}{2}$

Comment: is this correct @MXYMXY?

Comment: correction in my comment above, the $i$ was omitted there $c=\pm (\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}i)-1=\frac{\pm(\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{10}i)-2}{2‌​}$

Comment: @aravhinz I think it's correct.